# Tailwind 2.x Responsive aspect-ratio custom plugin

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have created a new utility plugin based on this one here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/SwA5mjOUtl?file=config

My question is how can I customise it to let it responsive?

the needed classes should work at the end like that:

```
class="aspect-3/4 md:aspect-4/3"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use it like `class="my-aspect-3/4 md:my-aspect-4/3"` as it was named during registration

```js
'my-aspect': (value) => ({
   'aspect-ratio': value
}),
```

If you wish to use `aspect-4/3`, name it respectively

```js
'aspect': (value) => ({
   'aspect-ratio': value
}),
```

Also there is a [plugin](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-aspect-ratio) for this - it should work with Tailwind v2

Comment: Already tried it with the right names with success...

Comment: Can see its [working](https://play.tailwindcss.com/eV7MAzlciZ) with v2.2 - switch view in right top corner. Maybe some conflict with other CSS?